# can equals() tell if an object sent and then recieved back is actually the same?

Tags: java, serialization, client-server

Im using the OCSF framework explained [here](http://www.site.uottawa.ca/school/research/lloseng/supportMaterial/ocsf/ocsf.html), assume i send originalMssg using sendToServer(Object msg) which uses java's Object streaming with a socket on the client side, and then on the server side i run sendToClient(Object msg) where the mssg object is the same as i recieved from that client.

now, consider the following callback which is called once the mssg has been recieved back from the server on the client side code:

```
@Override
protected void handleMessageFromServer(Object msg) {
  System.out.println(msg.equals(originalMssg));
    
}
```

1. on the above scenario will it always print true?
2. if not in what cases will it not? and is it possible to make it always return true?
3. if in all cases it returns false, how do can you mark your mssg object so that you can recognize it when it gets back from the server?

Comment: it depends on the implementation of equals() of the runtime object instance type you are transmitting. if you rely on Object default implementation, it tests against instance reference

Comment: @guido, and i guess what you mean is that instance reference wont make it return true right?

Comment: Right.  If the object class does not implement its own `equals` method then the default Object implementation simply compares references -- the same as you'd get with `objA == objB`.  In that case objA and objB must be the SAME object to be "equal".  But what the class considers "equal" is up to the class implementer, and does not guarantee that the two instances are identical in all characteristics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main proper of `OSCF` is to send String's or array of strings.....so first of all check if your object is `serializable`.

Then there is the `equals` method you need to `@Override` for each class you made.

1)NO.

2)Almost any time it's be false , you can try to sent a string a object and you should get true.

3)See my introduction to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

(This is purely based on reading the OSCF website and javadocs ... YMMV)

The website says that OSCF sends and receives plain Java objects (POJOs) that are serializable.  From this I infer that the `msg` object can be an instance of *any* serializable class.

> On the above scenario will it always print true?

It is not possible to say.  It depends on how the actual class implements `equals`.

> if not in what cases will it not?

Not possible to say (see above).

> and is it possible to make it always return true?

Ermm ... you would need to change the implementation of the `equals` method on the class you are sending / receiving.

> if in all cases it returns false ...

It is not possible to say if that precondition holds (see above).

---

Bottom line.  The `msg` is an instance of some class that you have implemented yourself or chosen.  It is up to you to implement / choose it with `equals` behaviour that suits your requirements ... including (apparently) comparison with instances of the object that have made the round-trip from the client to the server and back again.